# Hibernate 5.2.17 not rolling back failed transactions

Tags: java, hibernate

I'm currently in the process of updating a large project from Hibernate 5.1 to Hibernate 5.2.17 and I'm running into an issue that I'm struggling to resolve.

We have a suite of tests that are testing our DAOs using the H2 in-memory database, but some tests have started to fail on the updated version of Hibernate.

Some of the tests attempt to delete a `null` entity from the persistence context and expect the operation to fail with an `IllegalArgumentException`. With the new version of Hibernate the exception is still thrown as expected, but the transaction is no longer being rolled back and is being left active, and is consequently causing subsequent tests to fail because there's already an active transaction. Stack trace included below:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Transaction is still active when it should have been rolled back.
    at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
    at hibernatetest.persistence.HibernateTestDAOTest.testDeleteDetachedEntity(HibernateTestDAOTest.java:50)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.ExternalResource$1.evaluate(ExternalResource.java:48)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:538)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:760)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:206)
```

While investigating I noticed a similar difference in behaviour when attempting to delete a detached entity as well. I have been able to recreate the behaviour in a small, standalone project that can be found [here](https://github.com/KilgallonJ/Hibernate_5.2.17_Test). The project also includes configuration in the pom.xml (commented out) for running against Hibernate 5.0.10, where the tests pass with no issue and the failed transaction is correctly rolled-back.

While I haven't been able to recreate the error deleting a `null` entity, I have managed to recreate it with a detached entity, and I'm hoping the answer to why this is happening will help guide me to why it's also failing with `null` in the real code.

Are we doing something wrong here, or is this an issue with Hibernate itself?

Code also included below:

**pom.xml**:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>HibernateTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>HibernateTest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.7.0</maven.compiler.version>

        <!-- Uncomment this property to run as Hibernate 5.0.10 -->
        <!-- <hibernate.core.version>5.0.10.Final</hibernate.core.version> -->
        <!-- Uncomment this property to run as Hibernate 5.2.17 -->
        <hibernate.core.version>5.2.17.Final</hibernate.core.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <h2.version>1.4.197</h2.version>
        <javaee.api.version>7.0</javaee.api.version>

    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven.compiler.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Uncomment these dependencies to run using Hibernate 5.0.10 -->
        <!-- 
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-java8</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.core.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javaee.api.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>${h2.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**HibernateTest.java** (entity class):

```
package hibernatetest.persistence;

import java.util.UUID;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.annotations.Type;

@Entity
@Table(name = "hibernate_test")
public class HibernateTest {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @Type(type = "uuid-char")
    private UUID id;

    public HibernateTest(final UUID id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

**HibernateTestDAO.java**

```
package hibernatetest.persistence;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

public class HibernateTestDAO {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "hibernate-test")
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void delete(final HibernateTest entity) {
        entityManager.remove(entity);
    }
}
```

**EntityManagerRule.java** (JUnit Rule to provide the entity manager for the tests):

```
package hibernatetest.persistence;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.EntityTransaction;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;

import org.junit.rules.ExternalResource;

public class EntityManagerRule extends ExternalResource {

    private EntityManagerFactory emFactory;

    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    protected void before() {
        emFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("hibernate-test");
        em = emFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    @Override
    protected void after() {
        if (em != null) {
            em.close();
        }
        if (emFactory != null) {
            emFactory.close();
        }
    }

    public HibernateTestDAO initDAO() {
        final HibernateTestDAO dao = new HibernateTestDAO();

        try {
            injectEntityManager(dao);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return dao;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return em;
    }

    public void persist(final Object entity) {
        final EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
        transaction.begin();
        try {
            em.persist(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            transaction.rollback();
            throw e;
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void injectEntityManager(final HibernateTestDAO dao) throws Exception {
        final Field emField = dao.getClass().getDeclaredField("entityManager");
        emField.setAccessible(true);
        emField.set(dao, em);
    }
}
```

**HibernateTestDAOTest.java**:

```
package hibernatetest.persistence;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import java.util.UUID;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Rule;
import org.junit.Test;

public class HibernateTestDAOTest {

    @Rule
    public EntityManagerRule rule = new EntityManagerRule();

    private HibernateTestDAO dao;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        dao = rule.initDAO();
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeleteNullEntity() {
        HibernateTest entity = null;
        try {
            dao.delete(entity);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            if (rule.getEntityManager().getTransaction().isActive()) {
                fail("Transaction is still active when it should have been rolled back.");
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testDeleteDetachedEntity() {
        HibernateTest entity = new HibernateTest(UUID.randomUUID());
        rule.persist(entity);
        rule.getEntityManager().detach(entity);
        try {
            dao.delete(entity);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            if (rule.getEntityManager().getTransaction().isActive()) {
                fail("Transaction is still active when it should have been rolled back.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**persistence.xml** from `src/test/resources/META-INF`:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="hibernate-test" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <class>hibernatetest.persistence.HibernateTest</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:h2:mem:test;INIT=create schema if not exists test\;runscript from 'classpath:/populate.sql';DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.validation.mode" value="none"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**populate.sql** from `src/test/resources`:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS hibernate_test (
  id       UUID NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: You should inculded updated HibernateEntityManger for hibernate 5.2.17.<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.2.17.Final</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Why did you comment that?

Comment: The `hibernate-entitymanager` artifact is **not** required with Hibernate 5.2.  That artifact is just an empty artifact that no longer contains code since it was merged into `hibernate-core` in 5.2.0.Final and was left to avoid existing projects failing to find 5.x artifacts when you upgraded.

Comment: Are you sure getTransaction() does not create a new transaction if there is none in progress ?

Comment: @PaulJanssens No it does not.  You must specifically call `begin()` in order to start a new transaction with the JPA API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing in the spec states that when a call to `EntityManager#remove` fails that  the persistence provider should rollback the existing transaction, that just makes no sense.

If you look at all the examples in the Hibernate test suite, you'll notice this behavior:

```
EntityManager entityManager = getOrCreateEntityManager();
try {
  entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
  // do something
  entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
}
catch ( Exception e ) {
  if ( entityManager != null && entityManager.getTransaction.isActive() ) {
    entityManager.getTransaction().rollback();
  }
  throw e;
}
finally {
  if ( entityManager != null ) {
    entityManager.close();
  }
}
```

If your tests worked previously and no longer do in the same way, I'm not sure I'd necesssarily say that is a bug as the code which you've supplied above does not conform to what I have shown here with properly handling the rollback in user code unless you have spring or some other framework at play which you haven't illustrated.

But if you feel there is a regression between 5.1 and 5.2, you're welcomed to open a JIRA and report it with your reproducable test use case and we can do further investigation.

One key point to remember is that 5.2.x introduced the merging of the JPA artifact `hibernate-entitymanager` into `hibernate-core` proper, so there could be a regression here with that but its extremely unlikely.

Comment: I've suspected all along that it's a problem with our code rather than an issue with the hibernate framework - I've just been fighting with this for a little over a week now and I'm running out of ideas! The real code is running in Wildfly 12 (was upgraded from WF10 last week), but we aren't using the spring framework at all. The behaviour does seem to have changed between 5.0.10 and 5.2.17, and I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation *so far* that suggests it's intentional, but there also doesn't seem to be anyone else hitting this problem either...

Comment: Having slept on it you've convinced me that the problem is definitely at our end, and given me a good steer on how to correctly fix this. Thanks for the insight.